# Match SFDC records against external master list looking for missing elements

Tags: data, migration, search, data-migration

My team is in the process of migrating support tickets from ZenDesk to Salesforce. We have roughly 1,000 or so tickets with a unique number. Some made it into Salesforce, others didn't. We'd like to run a bulk search in Salesforce of each number to see which migrated and which didn't.

Is there a script or something I can run to bulk search a csv file or txt file with one ticket number on each time, and then return a value if the ticket is found or not found?

Comment: Vlookup in excel works pretty well to compare two files.  Especially if at th end of the day a .csv is need to load back to SFDC.  Extract the critical fields from SF with a report or query, run a vlookup against the unique ids . . . profit.